# data.matrix converts zero-values

Tags: r

I am trying to use R to analyse some data, though when I am trying to convert a data.frame (with zero-values) into a TimeSeries, it changes the values.

```
data <- input-dataset

    Qua1    Qua2    Qua3    Qua4
A      0       1       1       3 
B      0       1       0       0
C      0       2       0       0
D      1       1       3       0
```

I need to transpose these data and set the colnames, before further analysis

```
data = t(data)
colnames(data) <- data[1,]
data = data.frame(data[2:5,])
ts(data)
```

The data.frame keeps the inputvalues, but when I apply TS() (converts data.frame to numeric matrix via data.matrix) all zero's change to 1, the existing 1 to 2, and rest remains the same. As I would like to keep my zeros for later analysis, I would like to avoid this change-in-values, but how??

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Works fine.

Comment: Really? I still get the same thing, even though I tryed `rm(list=ls())` and started with just my example.

Comment: Try `data <- structure(list(Qua1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Qua2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), Qua3 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 3L), Qua4 = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Qua1", 
"Qua2", "Qua3", "Qua4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"))` and then `ts(t(data))`

Comment: That works great, though my actual dataset has 1018 obs. of 36 variables. Can I have my script to automaticly list the different values, based on the columns?